# In-memory SQLite context throws "no such table" exception

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I try to use In-memory SQLite database to improve my unit tests, my test looks like

```
[Fact]
public void CreateSampleType()
{
    var sampleType = new SampleType("Type One");

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SamplesContext>()
        .UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:")
        .Options;

    using (var context = new SamplesContext(options))
    {
          context.Database.EnsureCreated();

          context.SampleType.Add(sampleType);
          context.SaveChanges();
     };
}
```

the `context.SaveChanges();` line throws

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'no such
>   table: SampleType'.

the `SamplesContext` works when connected to SQL Server.

```
public class SamplesContext : DbContext
    {
        public SamplesContext(DbContextOptions<SamplesContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SampleType>().ToTable("SampleType", schema: "enum").HasKey("Id");
        }

        public virtual DbSet<SampleType> SampleType { get; set; }
    }
```

what am I missing ? :/

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a need to manually open a connection. This code example works

```
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:"))
{
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SamplesContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new SamplesContext(options))
        {
               context.Database.EnsureCreated();

               context.SampleType.Add(sampleType);
               context.SaveChanges();

               var items = context.SampleType.ToList();
               Assert.Single(items);
        };
}
```